# Improving Pattern-matching Code

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Assume the following data-structure.

```
sealed abstract class Formula {...}

//... some other case classes

sealed abstract class BinaryConnective(f0: Formula, f1: Formula) extends Formula {
  def getf0 = f0
  def getf1 = f1
}

object BinaryConnective {
  def unapply(bc : BinaryConnective) = Some((bc.getf0, bc.getf1))
}

final case class Conjunction(f0: Formula, f1: Formula) extends BinaryConnective(f0,f1)
final case class Disjunction(f0: Formula, f1: Formula) extends BinaryConnective(f0,f1)
final case class Implication(f0: Formula, f1: Formula) extends BinaryConnective(f0,f1)
final case class Equivalence(f0: Formula, f1: Formula) extends BinaryConnective(f0,f1)
```

I now wrote a function that has a lot of pattern-matching:

The return-type of `getCondition` is `Formula => Option[HashMap[Variable, Formula]]`

```
formula match {
//.. irrelevant cases not shown
case Conjunction(f0, f1) => (g : Formula) => {
    g match {
      case conj @ Conjunction(g0, g1) => {
        getCondition(f0)(conj.f0) match {
          case Some(map0) => {
            getCondition(f1)(conj.f1) match {
             case Some(map1) if map0.forall{case (key, value) => map1.get(key).map(_ == value).getOrElse(true)} => {
               Some(map0 ++ map1)
             }
             case _ => None
            }
          }
          case None => None
        }
      }
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

Now to my question.

1) Is there a nicer way to express this code? A lot of matches going on.

Edit 1: I could not think of a nice-looking way to use things like `map`, `filter` etc.., but it seems very compact with for-comprehensions. I've also noticed that `conj @` was not necessary at all, which also made it a little simpler.

```
case Conjunction(f0, f1) => (g: Formula) => g match {
  case Conjunction(g0, g1) => for {
      map0 <- getCondition(f0)(g0)
      map1 <- getCondition(f1)(g1)
      if map0.forall {case (key, value) => map1.get(key).map(_ ==  value).getOrElse(true)}
    } yield map0 ++ map1
  case _ => None
}
```

2) This is the match for `Conjunction`. I would have to repeat it for `Disjunction`, `Implication` and `Equivalence`. `g` has to be of the same class as `formula`. The only thing that would change is `case conj @ Conjunction(g0, g1)`. I would have to adjust it to `case disj @ Disjunction(g0, g1)` if `formula` is a Disjunction etc...
Is there a way to do it combined for all cases?

Comment: For 2), I may be missing something obvious but can't you use the parent class, if the code really is identical? `case BinaryConnnective(g0, g1)`?

Comment: Yes, I could match on `BinaryConnnective`. But if I match `formula` on `BinaryConnnective` and `g` on `BinaryConnnective`, how can I make sure that both are `Conjunction` or both are `Disjunction` etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Option` should provide a lot of useful functions to simplify your code.

For example, when you write something like:

```
o match {
  case Some(e) => Some(transform(e))
  case _ => None
}
```

You could just call `map`:  `o.map(transform)`

I also invite you to look at the `filter` function for the cases including a condition.

EDIT: great suggestion by @om-nom-nom: For comprehensions can also be used (they actually are sugar relying on `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc):

```
for{
  e <- o
} yield transform(e)
```

Comment: there are also for comprehensions

Comment: for-comprehensions were a great suggestion. So far I never used them on `Option`. New code is in Edit 1. Do u have an idea for my second problem?